# Get common name (CN) from SSL certificate?

Tags: openssl, certificates

I have a SSL CRT file in PEM format. Is there a way that I can extract the common name (CN) from the certificate from the command line?

Comment: Note, however, that in multi-domain certificates, CN does not contain all of them.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

If you have `openssl` installed you can run:

```
openssl x509 -noout -subject -in server.pem
```

Comment: You can extract the CN out of the subject with: `openssl x509 -noout -subject -in server.pem  | sed -n '/^subject/s/^.*CN=//p'`

Comment: I modified what @MatthewBuckett said and used `sed -e 's/^subject.*CN=\([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]*\).*$/\1/'` to get just the domain as I had additional details after the CN. Its not super strict matching for a valid CN but in most cases it works, you could be more slack and replace `[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]` with `[^/]` but I am not certain that would always work.

Comment: Add `\*` to what @flungo used to support wildcard domains: `sed -e 's/^subject.*CN=\([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-\*]*\).*$/\1/'` 
(`[^/]` works in my case, though)

Comment: The `sed` commands suggested above won't work if the cert has Relative Distinguished Names (RDNs) specified after the Common Name (CN), for example OU (OrganizationalUnit) or C (Country). One way to cater for such cases would be an additional `sed`: `openssl x509 -noout -subject -in server.pem | sed 's/^.*CN=//' | sed sed 's/\/.*$//'`.

Comment: **Easier way to separate** CN from other RDN/ATVs in Subject name: `openssl x509 -noout -subject -nameopt multiline | grep commonName` or for the value only `| sed -n 's/ *commonName *= //p'`

Comment: Hmm, I had to use my `.crt`, not my `.pem` but otherwise it worked. Not sure if something's set up differently (MacOS, `OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016`)

Comment: Simpler alternative to @dave_thompson_085 `sed` for getting the value after `grep commonName` is `| awk '{print $3}'`

Answer (score 13):

```
certtool -i < whatever.pem | egrep "^\s+Subject:"
```

Notice that's directing the file to standard input via `<`, not using it as argument.  Sans `egrep` this will print the whole certificate out, but the CN is in the `Subject:` field near the top (beware there's also a CN value in the `Issuer:` field).

```
X.509 Certificate Information:
    Version: 3
    Serial Number (hex): 01
    Issuer: [...] CN=unixandlinux.ex  <- Not this one.
    Validity: ...
    Subject: CN=goldilocks
```

`certtool` is part of gnutls, if it is not installed just search for that.  GnuTLS is a little nicer than OpenSSL, IMO.

Comment: Good answer, +1. For Mac OS X, I had to use `gnutls-certtool` which was installed via `brew install gnutls`

Comment: on debian install `gnutls-bin`

Answer (score 3):

I found the above answer, and found it to be very useful, but I also found that the `certtool` command syntax *(on Ubuntu Linux, today)* was noticeably different than described by goldilocks, as was the output. So, I thought it best to update that excellent answer with what might be "today's version."

The `"i"` option *(now?)* stands for "import," according to `man certtool`, so the proper command appears to be `"d"`, "display."  So, this command:

```
certtool d myfoo.crt
```

*(The file-extension in my case just happens to be `.crt` not `.pem` ... this is not relevant.)*

... produces output that, in relevant part, looks like this:

```
Common Name     : Foobar
```

Unquestionably, goldilocks was right: `certtool` output is *much* easier easier to work with than `openssl` in this case.

Comment: I suspect we are talking about completely different pieces of software.  I have never seen a version of `certtool` that took options sans the usual operators (`-` or `--`), and `man certtool` for v. 3.5.8 (debian), 3.5.16 (fedora, the only version after that in the upstream stable branch is 3.5.17 from a month ago), GnuTLS's [online documentation](https://www.gnutls.org/manual/html_node/certtool-Invocation.html) and, indeed, the [online man page for Ubuntu 17.10](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/man1/certtool.1.html) (same version as current debian) all refer to:

Comment: *"-i, --certificate-info: Print information on the given certificate,"* whereas *"-d"* is *"--debug".*  Very strange. O_o?

Answer (score 2):

Using openssl and awk

- *openssl*

  - `-subject` extracts only the subject, `-multiline` splits it to lines
- *awk*

  - `-F' = '` - Separate the fields by `<space>=<space>`
  - `/commonName/` for only the lines that match `commonName`
  - `{print $2}` - print the second field

```
❯ openssl x509 -noout -subject -in cert.crt -nameopt multiline    
subject=
    countryName               = AU
    stateOrProvinceName       = NSW
    localityName              = Sydney
    organizationName          = Some Acme Company Pty Ltd
    organizationalUnitName    = Engineering
    commonName                = CommonName 123
    emailAddress              = engineering-support@acme.com.au

❯ openssl x509 -noout -subject -in cert.crt -nameopt multiline | awk -F' = ' '/commonName/ {print $2}'
CommonName 123
```

Comment: For more robust processing, you want to match only `$1` against `commonName`.

Answer (score 1):

I ended using:

```
openssl x509 -inform DER -noout -subject -nameopt oneline,-esc_msb -in test.pem | sed 's/.*CN = //' | sed 's/, OU =.*$//' | sed 's/\"//g'
```

Notice the `-nameopt oneline,-esc_msb` which allows a valid output when the CN (common name) has special characters like accents for example.

`sed 's/.*CN = //'` removes the first part up to CN =

`sed 's/, OU =.*$//'` removes the last part from , OU =

`sed 's/\"//g'` Removes the quotes if any, noticed that sometimes CN comes with quotes and sometimes not.

Pretty sure there nicer and shorter ways to do it, but this one did the trick to me.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I have found that some certs have values that are displayed by *openssl* on the same line as the *commonName*, separated by +.

I think this is dependent on how the subject common name is formed -- it seems to be possible to make the CN value a sequence of multiple subvalues.

An example of this is *emailAddress*, which can come out as `commonName=Joe Bloggs + emailAddress=joe@example.org`, even when using *-nameopt multiline*.

To get around this, my alternative is to use `openssl asn1parse` instead:

```shell
openssl asn1parse -in '/pathto/thecert.crt' |\
  awk -v FS=':' -v OFS='' '
    BEGIN          {e=0} 
    e==2           {$1="";$2="";$3="";print;exit} 
    /:commonName$/ {e++}
  '
```

Comment: I'm sure the output format of `openssl asn1parse` will *never* change and it will *never* come back to bite me... */s*

Answer (score 0):

I used:
`openssl x509 -noout -subject -in mycert.crt | awk -F= '{print $NF}'` add `| sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//'` If you can't live with the white space